# Storing JWT in session based cookie Angular 6

Tags: angular, cookies, jwt, session-cookies, auth0

I am new to Angular development and would like to know what is the correct way of storing JWT?

I am working on app developed in Angular 6.1 single page app using Auth0 authentication.

After authentication has taken place Auth0 returns a JWT (access token(jwt)) and the app then stores it in local storage.  The client app  then makes a post call to a [authorize] decorated method in api(MVC C#) to validate the access to the api resources. The api is using OWIN and does the validation.

Although the access token has issuer and audience values  in it which is checked by the OWIN middleware but my concern is can anyone access it from local storage and reuse it later and by pass the login process?

Should I store the "access_token" in session cookie on server side?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116898/why-are-cookies-considered-more-secure-against-xss

Answer (score 3):

Storing "access_token" on the server side is bad idea because it break the main purpose of stateless JWT Auth. Going this way you can just implement any other kind of authorization on back-end side like old, good sessions stored in database, and no JWT is needed.

JWT have to be stateless and it's true -> somebody can reuse your token. BUT you can implement nice trick **to prevent this unsecure situation**. You can just **generate JWT with user IP address inside** (add IP address into the JWT content).

Thanks to this you can implement pure logic in your authorization middleware (some preAuth hook?) that will validate if request IP is equal to IP stored in JWT. If IP address changed then probably somebody stole the token.

Comment: If you will be using your app from a mobile device connected to 3g/4g like networks IP addresses can change pretty frequently.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote Although the access token has issuer and audience values in it which is checked by the OWIN middleware but my concern is can anyone access it from local storage and reuse it later and by pass the login process?

Yes they can reuse it. But you can set expiration time for main token and create refresh token as well and refresh it in X time main token and refresh token, when main token is expired you ask for refresh token and if it valid you refreshing two tokens. This better than endless access token, that some one can reuse. You implement this logic in interceptor, when token is expired from backend you returning status 403 and when you get this status on frontend you sending the main token and refresh token to backend to refresh it. And if two tokens are valid you refresh it, else you disconnect user.